# Signup page in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html5

I've written some `PHP` code that connects to a database and saves input entered by the user at our signup page. I would like some feedback before I present this code to my colleagues, as I intend on using this code for our website:

- Security
- Use of PDO vs other connection methods
- Variable Naming
- PHP Conventions
- HTML Conventions
- Anything else

**sign_up.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Sign Up</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/dropdown.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script src="scripts/empties.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- Nav Bar -->
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home" style="font-size: 40px"></i></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Signup Area -->
        <div id="sign_up_area">
            <form action="sign_up.php" method="post">
                <input id="form_input" 
                       type="text" 
                       placeholder="First Name" 
                       name="firstname"><br />
                <input id="form_input" 
                       type="text" 
                       placeholder="Last Name"
                       name="lastname"><br />
                <input id="form_input"
                       type="text" 
                       placeholder="Age"
                       name="age"><br />
                <input id="form_input" 
                       type="text" 
                       placeholder="Email"
                       name="email"><br />
                <input id="form_input" 
                       type="password" 
                       placeholder="Password"
                       name="password"><br />
                <button id="signup_button" type="submit" disabled>Sign Up</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**sign_up.php**

```
<?php

include 'config/database.php';

try {

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$DB_HOST;dbname=Database", $DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $firstname = filter_var($_POST["firstname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $lastname = filter_var($_POST["lastname"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $password = filter_var($_POST["password"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    #No need to hash name and email, can be used to check duplicates
    $password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Users (FirstName, LastName, Email, Password) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password_hash);
    $stmt->execute();

    header("Location: signed_up.html");

} catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();

}

?>
```

Comment: Echoing the error message right away is a bad practice. See my [PHP error reporting basics](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting). Also, filter_var is mostly misused

Comment: @YourCommonSense Please don't answer in comments. Any issues you see with the code should be mentioned in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I see multiple instances of `id="form_input"`. These attributes need to change to `class` or each `id` attribute value should be altered to be unique.
- Instead of using `<br>` tags to style your input fields on separate lines, use css.  By setting all of the elements in the form as `display:block;`, you can eliminate the excess markup -- a cleaner alternative.  CSS should be the first technique to create spacing and layout stylings; when you find yourself creating spaces with the spacebar or with `<br>`, try to achieve the same effect with `display`, `margin`, `padding`, etc.
- [11 reasons why placeholders are problematic](https://medium.com/simple-human/10-reasons-why-placeholders-are-problematic-f8079412b960) -- I can appreciate that you intend to design a clean, minimalist layout, but I don't think I support non-labeled fields and your project should maintain a consistent theme considering that your project may eventually need to employ more forms.
- In addition to the previous bullet point about UX, I will urge you to add some client-side validation to your form.  These character limitations will be up to you.  I assume `empties.js` is doing something that enables the submit button, but I can't see it.  If `empties.js` is as functionally narrow a file as it's name suggests, you may want to build more robust processes in there.
- Rather than sanitizing server-side and unconditionally inserting into the database, you should be catching overtly "bad" submissions and denying access.
- If a submitted password contains html markup, that is no concern of yours (no need to sanitize) because you will never, ever be printing that value -- ever.  More clearly: **never alter someone's submitted password characters**.
- You must never, ever present the raw error message to the end user.  See [@YCS's hyperlink](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting).  Especially with registration forms, you need to find the correct balance between informing the registrant why the submission was denied, yet not compromising the security of your project.
- Finally, login/registration systems are widely available now.  If you are doing this as an educational exercise, then carry on.  If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, just use a pre-existing script from a security-minded author.